# How to restart a process after it died

Tags: bash, process

I'm writing some monitoring routines like this one :

```
 tail -f /var/log/router-home.log | while read line ; do
   echo "$line" | egrep "MTF_SIP" | cut -b 28- | sed -u 's/#012/\n/g' \
   | egrep "IPP-->Received Event|rvCCConnMdmNewDigitCB|rvCCCallHandleOutOfBandDTMF" \
   | cut -d " " -f 15
 done > /tmp/phone/status &
```

but every time logrotation comes along it changes the `/var/log/router-home.log` killing the process
having more than one on this routines i cannot check it status just by doing a `ps -e|grep tail`

How can I monitor this routine and restart it when it dies ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to follow the file *name* rather than descriptor (so you get the latest file even if something like `logrotate` moves it underneath you), you can use `tail -F` which is basically:

```
tail --follow=name --retry
```

What I normally do is to run:

```
tail -F somefile 2>/dev/null
```

so I don't see the error messages when the file changes. You can try this by ensuring that `somefile` does not exist then running that command. Then, from another session:

```
echo pax is a >somefile
rm somefile
echo wonderful person >somefile
```

and you'll see both those lines appear in the `tail` output.

With that solution, the process *shouldn't* die, hence there won't be a need to restart it.

Comment: @KasperJanMooijman - Don't forget to click the checkmark beside the best answer.

Comment: Thanks for notifying me, i have to get used to this site

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to turn you script into system daemon (for instance, [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/135859/is-there-a-standard-way-to-make-daemon-in-debian) is a hint how to to this under Debian), also you get good logging and control of you process.

Also you may simply [trap](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/use-bash-trap-statement-cleanup-temporary-files) the desired signal (SIGHUP maybe?) and instead of exiting, reopen log file (restart your process).

```
trap ". /path/to/my-script.sh" SIGHUP
```

where `/path/to/my-script.sh` is a file with given code.